# "Con una pegada más demoledora que tiene alguien" vs "Con una pegada más demoledora que la de alguien"

Tags: gramática

Vi algunos ejemplos:

Desde "La Víctima Número Ocho": *estamos en una cacería....**La de** Omar Jamal.*

Desde "El Arte de no amalgarse la vida": *Otra de las obligaciones que nos inventamos es **la de** ayudar, aconsejar o...*

Creo que entiendo como usar esta construcción y su significado. Al mismo tiempo, quisiera comprobar si lo entiendo de una forma correcta. Vi el combate del boxeo "Mike Tyson vs Trevor Berbick" y construí las siguientes frases:

*Tyson con una pegada más demoledora que tiene Berbick.*

*Tyson con una pegada más demoledora que **la de** Berbick.*

Preguntas:

1. ¿Mi segunda frase es correcta?
2. ¿Hay alguna diferencia en significado entre las frases? Supongo que no.
3. ¿Podría usar esta construcción en plural, como: "*Tyson con unas habilidades más poderosas que **las de** Berbick*"? Pregunto porque nunca lo he visto en plural.

P.S. Por adelantado les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores en mi letra si haya algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tyson con una pegada más demoledora que tiene Berbick.
>
> Tyson con una pegada más demoledora que la de Berbick.

En realidad, la segunda frase es correcta y la primera no. La primera debería ser:

- Tyson con una pegada más demoledora que **la que tiene** Berbick.

La segunda resulta ser una versión más resumida de la primera.

Las frases nominales introducidas por "el de / los de / la de / las de" y similares (*el que/los que/los que/las que*) se consideran frases pronominales (con núcleo pronominal) o frases nominales introducidas por artículo y con sustantivo omitido:

> Tyson con una pegada más demoledora que **la (pegada) que tiene** Berbick.
>
> Tyson con una pegada más demoledora **que la (pegada) de** Berbick.

Por lo tanto, la frase "Tyson con unas habilidades más poderosas que las de Berbick" también es gramaticalmente correcta (sólo que no es común usar el adjetivo "poderoso" para referirnos a una "habilidad"). Tal vez hablaríamos de "habilidades inusuales".